Line Spacing in Table Environment (Tabularray)
I am trying to clean up the last row of my table (Particle Motion line with integrals) by adding some space between each line.  Although each set of text is on a new line, it feels cramped.  How do I increase the space between text?  Is there a cleaner way to write it?
Thank you for your time:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines,colspec={XX}}
        \SetCell[c=2]{c} Given a definite integral in context: \(\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} f\left(x\right)\, dx\) \\
        \Large{\textbf{Net Change}} &   \Large{\textbf{Total Amount}} \\
        \textbf{Use when}\ldots     & \textbf{Use when}\ldots\\
        \textbf{Example:} For \(0\leq t\leq 20\) minutes, the number of students at Flint Hill US is changing at the rate of \(S^{\prime}\left(t\right)\), measured in students per minute.  Using correct units, interpret the meaning of \(\displaystyle\int_{1}^{8} S^{\prime}\left(t\right)\, dt\) in the context of the problem. & \textbf{Example:} For \(0\leq t\leq 20\) minutes, students enter Flint Hill US at the rate of \(S^{\prime}\left(t\right)\), measured in students per minute.  Using correct units, interpret the meaning of \(\displaystyle\int_{1}^{8} S^{\prime}\left(t\right)\, dt\) in the context of the problem.  \\
    
    \textbf{Model Answer:} Given \(\displaystyle\int_{1}^{8} S^{\prime}\left(t\right)=143\) &   \textbf{Model Answer:} Given \(\displaystyle\int_{1}^{8} S^{\prime}\left(t\right)=143\) \\[1in]

\Large{\textbf{Important Tips, Strategies, and Ideas}}  &   \Large{\textbf{Important Tips, Strategies, and Ideas}} \\
    \\[2in]
    
\textbf{Particle Motion}\(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{4} v\left(t\right) \, dt\)

Net Change =Displacement

\large{\textbf{Interpretation:}} &\textbf{Particle Motion}\(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{4} v\left(t\right) \, dt\)

Total amount = Total Distance 

\large{\textbf{Interpretation:}}  \\ [1in]
    \end{tblr}


\end{document}



Like this:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines,colspec={XX},cell{8}{1,2}={cmd=\parskip0.5cm}}
        \SetCell[c=2]{c} Given a definite integral in context: \(\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} f\left(x\right)\, dx\) \\
        \Large{\textbf{Net Change}} &   \Large{\textbf{Total Amount}} \\
        \textbf{Use when}\ldots     & \textbf{Use when}\ldots\\
        \textbf{Example:} For \(0\leq t\leq 20\) minutes, the number of students at Flint Hill US is changing at the rate of \(S^{\prime}\left(t\right)\), measured in students per minute.  Using correct units, interpret the meaning of \(\displaystyle\int_{1}^{8} S^{\prime}\left(t\right)\, dt\) in the context of the problem. & \textbf{Example:} For \(0\leq t\leq 20\) minutes, students enter Flint Hill US at the rate of \(S^{\prime}\left(t\right)\), measured in students per minute.  Using correct units, interpret the meaning of \(\displaystyle\int_{1}^{8} S^{\prime}\left(t\right)\, dt\) in the context of the problem.  \\
    
    \textbf{Model Answer:} Given \(\displaystyle\int_{1}^{8} S^{\prime}\left(t\right)=143\) &   \textbf{Model Answer:} Given \(\displaystyle\int_{1}^{8} S^{\prime}\left(t\right)=143\) \\[1in]

\Large{\textbf{Important Tips, Strategies, and Ideas}}  &   \Large{\textbf{Important Tips, Strategies, and Ideas}} \\
    \\[2in]
    
\textbf{Particle Motion}\(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{4} v\left(t\right) \, dt\)

Net Change =Displacement

\large{\textbf{Interpretation:}} &\textbf{Particle Motion}\(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{4} v\left(t\right) \, dt\)

Total amount = Total Distance 

\large{\textbf{Interpretation:}}  \\ [1in]
    \end{tblr}


\end{document}



Thank you for your help!
